# How can I uncheck checkbox on attribute selection

Tags: javascript

I am adding some jscode to worpress. What I am trying to do is to uncheck all and only the checkbox contained on addon.product-addon-grand-accompagnement class when an attribute is selected.
I have tried:

```
$('.product-addon.product-addon-grand-accompagnement').prop('checked', false);

$('.product-addon.product-addon-grand-accompagnement').attr('checked', false);
```

but no success.

```js
// works but unchecks all the checkboxes which is not what i am looking for. 
$(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

```html
<div class="product-addon product-addon-grand-accompagnement checkbox" style="display: block;">
  <h3 class="addon-name">Grand Accompagnement</h3>
  <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-4280-grand-accompagnement-2-0">
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="addon addon-checkbox"
        name="addon-4280-grand-accompagnement-2[]"
        data-raw-price=""
        data-price=""
        value="grande-frite"> Grande Frite
    </label>
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-4280-grand-accompagnement-2-1">
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        class="addon addon-checkbox"
        name="addon-4280-grand-accompagnement-2[]"
        data-raw-price=""
        data-price=""
        value="grande-patatoes"> Grande Patatoes
      </label>
  </p>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the class name to uncheck, it will uncheck all classes with that same class name. You have to use a unique ID to uncheck a specific checkbox.

Add an id value to each input tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id1" class="addon addon-checkbox" name="addon-4280-grand-accompagnement-2[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="grande-patatoes">
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id2" class="addon addon-checkbox" name="addon-4280-grand-accompagnement-2[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="grande-patatoes">
```

Then uncheck with #id1 or #id2

```
$("#id1").prop('checked', false);
```